# I want to make a voip Call using my program ()

Tags: android, asterisk, sip, voip

I'm currently developing an application for making VoIP/SIP calls
but I don't know why I cannot register my RegistrationListener i don't know what is the probleme 
i use asterisk as a sip provider;

this is my code

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CALL_ADDRESS = 1;
Button Connect_Button;
public SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile MyProfile = null;
public String sipAddress = null;

public CommsController cc;

public Context ctx = this;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Connect_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConnectB);




            cc = new CommsController();
            cc.createManager(this);

            cc.createProfile("example","192.168.1.29","54321");

            cc.openProfile(ctx);

            try {
                System.out.println("+++ IS API SUPPORTED: " + cc.getManager().isApiSupported(this));
                System.out.println("+++ IS VOIP SUPORTED: " + cc.getManager().isVoipSupported(this));
                System.out.println("+++ MANAGER INSTANCE: " + cc.getManager().toString());
                boolean isOpened = cc.getManager().isOpened(cc.getMe().getUriString());
                System.out.println("+++ IS OPENED: "+isOpened);

                if(isOpened){

                    cc.createRegistrationListener();
                    cc.getManager().register(cc.getMe(), 30000, cc.getSrl());





                }

            }catch(SipException sipex){
                System.out.println(sipex.getCause()+", "+ sipex.getMessage());

            }
}



public Context getContext(){return ctx;}

public CommsController getCc() {
    return cc;
}
```

}

**Controller**

```
public class CommsController {

public String sipAddress = null;
public SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile me = null;
public SipAudioCall call = null;
public Context ctx;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
public SipRegistrationListener srl;



private static final int CALL_ADDRESS = 1;
private static final int SET_AUTH_INFO = 2;
private static final int UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG = 3;
private static final int HANG_UP = 4;

SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener(){
    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
        call.startAudio();
        call.setSpeakerMode(true);
        call.toggleMute();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
        // Do something.
    }
};

public void createManager(Context context) {
    if (manager == null) {
        manager = SipManager.newInstance(context);
    }
}

public boolean createProfile(String uname, String domain, String pass){

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(uname, domain);
        builder.setPassword(pass);
        builder.setProtocol("TCP");
        builder.setPort(5060);
        me = builder.build();
        setMe(me);
        System.out.println("+++ User Profile = CREATED");
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("+++ User Profile = FAILED");

    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public void openProfile(Context context){
    try {
        System.out.println("+++ ATTEMPTING TO OPEN PROFILE: " + me.getUriString());

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(getMe(),pendingIntent,srl);
        System.out.println("+++ IS OPEN IN CC: " +manager.isOpened(getMe().getUriString()));

    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("+++ Profile Registration = FAILED");
    }
}

public void createRegistrationListener(){
    System.out.println("+++ CREATING REG LISTENER...");

    srl = new SipRegistrationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
            System.out.println("+++ REGISTERING...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
            System.out.println("+++ READY");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
            System.out.println("+++ REGISTRATION FAILED. CHECK SETTINGS. ERROR: "+ errorCode + " MESSAGE: " +errorMessage);
        }
    };

}
public SipRegistrationListener getSrl(){
    return srl;
}

public void closeProfile(SipProfile toClose){
    if(manager==null){
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.close(toClose.getUriString());
            System.out.println("PROFILE CLOSED: " +toClose.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("FAILED TO CLOSE LOCAL PROFILE: "+ toClose.toString());
    }

}

public void logOut(){
    try {
        System.out.println("+++ DEREGISTERING...");
        manager.close(me.getUriString());
    }catch(SipException se){
        System.out.println("+++ DEREGISTRATION FAILED");
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void makeCall(String toCall){
    try {
        call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), toCall, listener, 30);
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setMe(SipProfile me) {
    this.me = me;
}

public SipProfile getMe() {
    return me;
}

public SipManager getManager() {
    return manager;
}

public void setManager(SipManager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}
```

}

**Output**

```
I/System.out: +++ User Profile = CREATED
I/System.out: +++ ATTEMPTING TO OPEN PROFILE:  sip:example@192.168.1.29;transport=tcp
I/System.out: +++ IS OPEN IN CC: true
I/System.out: +++ IS API SUPPORTED: true
I/System.out: +++ IS VOIP SUPORTED: true
I/System.out: +++ MANAGER INSTANCE: android.net.sip.SipManager@41bccd58
I/System.out: +++ IS OPENED: true
I/System.out: +++ CREATING REG LISTENER...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
I/System.out: +++ REGISTRATION FAILED. CHECK SETTINGS. ERROR: -4 MESSAGE:   libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

**Please HELP ME...**

Answer (score 1):

There are no way ANSWER this, becuase it is debug issue, not a question.

Proposed way of debug is following:

1. Get 100% working softphone, for example zoiper or xlite
2. Connect it to asterisk.
3. Get wireshark or tcpdump and get dump of sip packets
4. Get dump for your project
5. Compare.